# Horizontal comment form submit

Tags: html, css

i need some help for css design. I have a textarea and a button. I want to put side by side. But when i made it the button is going a little under textarea. [image: This is the picture of my error. I dont want this]

```html
    <textarea 
style="width:411px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px; height:50px;"
placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" style="Height: 50px;">
```

Comment: I don't see your code.

Comment: Post the HTML/CSS if you'd like help.

Comment: Oh damn, avoid inlining style please

Comment: I added a picture and html tags

Comment: On the right answers, just make your code in one line to avoid the gap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `vertical-align: top;` to both and remove `margin-top` from texatrea

```
<textarea style="width:411px; margin-left: 3px; height:50px; vertical-align: top;" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" style="Height: 50px; vertical-align: top;">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a3epw1w4/1/

Answer (score 3):

Declare the following styles to your input button:

```
vertical-align: top;
margin-top: 3px;
```

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```css
input[type="submit"] {
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<textarea style="width:411px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px; height:50px;" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" style="Height: 50px;">
```

`input` elements are computed as `inline-block` elements as default, this means you can use `vertical-align`, in this case, to vertically align it as required.
The `margin-top` rule has been declared to offset the the spacing deficit created above the element in question as a result of its sibling element, the `textarea`, having the same `margin-top` property declared.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you don't use `float` ( left or right ) . Might cause other alignment issues in your code.

Use instead `vertical-align:top` and `margin-top:3px` ( equal to the margin-top of textarea )

( the input by default has `display:inline-block` )

Also i suggest you don't use inline styling. They are a pain to read,edit,change,overwrite etc.

```html
<textarea style="width:411px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px; height:50px;" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" style="Height: 50px;display: inline-block;margin-top:3px;vertical-align:top">
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
input[type="submit"]{
 padding:5px 15px;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<textarea  rows="4" cols="45" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!">
</body>
</html>
```

This code will help you

Answer (score 1):

align everything in the middle using `vertical-align: middle;`
Please separate your `css` and your `html`

```css
textarea
{
  width:411px; 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  margin-left: 3px; 
  height:50px;  
  vertical-align: middle;
}
input
{
    height: 50px; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the **Flexbox**:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <textarea style="width:400px; margin-right:5px" placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
  <input style="height:50px" type="submit" value="Do it!">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `float: left;` to the `textarea` and `margin-top: 6px;margin-left: 10px` to `input` which will make it beside each others in one line.

```html
<textarea 
style="width:411px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px; height:50px;float: left;"
placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Do it!" style="Height: 50px;margin-top: 6px;margin-left: 10px;">
```

Comment: Yes but this is too situational, it doesn't work on every screen size and every browser

Comment: certainly it won't work on every screen since he specified a fixed width for `textarea` regardless it will work on every browser since the `float` and `margin` are supported by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<textarea placeholder="Comment" style="width: 411px; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px; height: 50px; float: left;"></textarea>
<input type="submit" style="height: 50px; float: left; margin-top: 3px; margin-left: 3px;" value="Do it!">
```